# How to delay an app's closure till all the code finishes executing?

Tags: java, android, android-dialog

I have a dialog that tells the user that their trial has ended and then redirects them to the full version on the Play Store. When the dialog is dismissed the app should close so that the user can no longer use it. Problem is that sometimes this leads to the app getting closed before it gets the chance to open the Play Store link.

Here's the dialog:

```
private void showTrialEndedDialog() {
    MaterialAlertDialogBuilder builder = new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this, R.style.MaterialAlertDialog_regular);
    builder.setTitle("Trial ended")
            .setMessage("To continue using the app you can purchase the full version from the Play Store")
            .setPositiveButton("Go to Play Store", (dialog, which) -> {
                final String appPackageName = "com.braapproductions.redalertemulatorpro";
                try {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName)));
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", (dialog, which) -> {

            })
            .setOnDismissListener(dialog -> closeApp())
            .create().show();
  
}


public void closeApp() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        finishAndRemoveTask(); //closes the application
    } else {
        finishAffinity();
        System.exit(0); //use these two lines of code are for older versions of android
    }
}
```

Most of the time when pressing the button to go to the Play Store, the app just closes instead of opening the Play Store link, though it does work sometimes. So apparently the app is being closed before the `startActivity()` command is reached. How can I make it wait till everything is finished before it closes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I make it wait till everything is finished before it closes?

Don't try to "close" your app.

**Your Problem**

When you open the app store that instance of the activity is in your app's task list. Therefore calling `finishAndRemoveTask` will close the app store along with your app.

**A Solution**

Just use a regular `finish` call - killing the entire task is unnecessary.

```
.setOnDismissListener(dialog -> finish())
```

And definitely avoid using `System.exit(0)` - that's an anti-pattern. Worry about your Activities - let the Android framework worry your app's process.

Comment: Let me try it and report back

Comment: "`finishAndRemoveTask` will close the app store along with your app". Not totally true. On prelollipop it happens that. But on lollipop+ it not gona close the "play store" because the intent sent by the app to the play store app creates a new task for the new activity (play store).

Comment: "the intent sent by the app to the play store app creates a new task for the new activity (play store)" - the intent sent by the app is controlled by the app. Unless it specifies a "new task" flag, it's not just going to magically spawn a new task. I tested on my Pixel 3a running latest Android and it fails as expected.

Comment: Try the code in my answer on your pixel 3a and you'll see.

Comment: As discussed in the comments of your answer, it's clear that code won't work to do what the OP is trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You could post a delay using a Handler before closing the app:

```
public void closeApp() {
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                finishAndRemoveTask(); //closes the application
            } else {
                finishAffinity();
                System.exit(0); //use these two lines of code are for older versions of android
            }
        }
    }, 3000); // 3 seconds
}
```

Comment: Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: @purchaseTest Probably you can call `closeApp()` in `onStop()`  callback which means the app goes to the background whenever the play store gets open.. but just make sure that you just closed the dialog

Comment: You mean in `onPause()`?

Comment: Either can work, the `onPause()` is called just before `onStop` but make sure that is not called in other times the dialog wasn't just opened

Answer (score -1):

```
private void showTrialEndedDialog() {
        MaterialAlertDialogBuilder builder = new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this);
        AlertDialog builderDialog;
        builder.setTitle("Trial ended")
                .setMessage("To continue using the app you can purchase the full version from the Play Store")
                .setPositiveButton("Go to Play Store", (dialog, which) -> {

                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", (dialog, which) -> {

                })
                .setOnDismissListener(dialog -> closeApp());
                builderDialog = builder.create();
                builderDialog.show();
                builderDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(view -> {
                    final String appPackageName = "com.braapproductions.redalertemulatorpro";
                    try {
                        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
                    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName)));
                    }
                    builderDialog.dismiss();
                });

    }


    public void closeApp() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            finishAndRemoveTask(); //closes the application
        } else {
            finishAffinity();
            System.exit(0); //use these two lines of code are for older versions of android
        }
    }
```

Comment: But then the dialog can just be dismissed by pressing the back button or pressing outside of it

Comment: @purchaseTest Check now. I edited the code a little bit. Now when you click the positive button it not gona dismiss until the all the code inside the `onClick` method is done.

Comment: So I tried it and it gives the same result as the original, meaning the app often closes before the play store is opened

Comment: Maybe the problem is your Internet conection. If the code inside the positive button is executed and there is no internet connection, it not gona open the playstore; unless your don't have the play store app installed, in which case it gona open your browser app to search your target app.

Comment: The problem is not internet connection. This suggestion is basically the same as the original issue - you just moved the logic from the positive button click to ... a click on the positive button ... either way you are doing what I explain in my answer: taking down the task that has the play store app in it.